# Fitting multivariate linear mixed model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model

I'm wondering how to fit multivariate linear mixed model and finding multivariate BLUP in R. I'd appreciate if someone come up with example and R code.

**Edit**

I wonder how to fit multivariate linear mixed model with `lme4`. I fitted univariate linear mixed models with the following code:

```
library(lme4)
lmer.m1 <- lmer(Y1 ~ A*B + (1|Block) + (1|Block:A), data=Data)
summary(lmer.m1)
anova(lmer.m1)

lmer.m2 <- lmer(Y2 ~ A*B + (1|Block) + (1|Block:A), data=Data)
summary(lmer.m2)
anova(lmer.m2)
```

I'd like to know how to fit multivariate linear mixed model with `lme4`. The data is below:

```
Block A B    Y1    Y2
 1 1 1 135.8 121.6
 1 1 2 149.4 142.5
 1 1 3 155.4 145.0
 1 2 1 105.9 106.6
 1 2 2 112.9 119.2
 1 2 3 121.6 126.7
 2 1 1 121.9 133.5
 2 1 2 136.5 146.1
 2 1 3 145.8 154.0
 2 2 1 102.1 116.0
 2 2 2 112.0 121.3
 2 2 3 114.6 137.3
 3 1 1 133.4 132.4
 3 1 2 139.1 141.8
 3 1 3 157.3 156.1
 3 2 1 101.2  89.0
 3 2 2 109.8 104.6
 3 2 3 111.0 107.7
 4 1 1 124.9 133.4
 4 1 2 140.3 147.7
 4 1 3 147.1 157.7
 4 2 1 110.5  99.1
 4 2 2 117.7 100.9
 4 2 3 129.5 116.2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question cannot motivate any decent answer as it stands. You might consider adding information about your design (crossed effects--random or not--vs. nested ones), what you qualify as multivariate (is this on the response variable(s) or the number of predictors), etc.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 8):

Fitting multivariate models with `lme4` or `nlme`is a bit fiddly, but solutions can be found in this [document by Ben Bolker](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/3336).

Else if you want to stay in a frequentist framework, the `mcglm` package can handle multivariate models, even with non-normal distributions. A detailed tutorial should be published soon. If you are not familiar with design matrices, designing the matrix of random effects can be a bit tricky though.

In a Bayesian framework, the `MCMCglmm` package is also very good at modelling multivariate traits incl. non-normal distributions, and handles random effects in a simpler way than `mcglm` does. Its use for multivariate models is also well described by [Ben Bolker](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/3336). But you first have to make yourself familiar with Markov chain Monte Carlo, as well as with the principles of Bayesian statistics.

So either way, there might be a slow learning curve at the beginning, depending on your familiarity with either methods!

Comment: The links in the document by Ben Bolker are broken, currently you can find those course notes at: http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf on pg. 90

Answer (score 2):

Try the R package `nlme`

You can find some examples, theory and further documentation in: 
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-mixed-models.pdf

The `nlme` package is able to calculate pooled estimates [or the so called BLUP= best linear unbiased predictor].

Once you've downloaded the package, type in R console: `help(predict.lme)`

For more information, look at page 17 in Fox's paper. There you can find an example on how to pool information across subjects.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: These are univariate BLUP. But I'm looking for multivariate BLUP.