# Alternative to chi-square where independence assumption is broken

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, multivariate-analysis, contingency-tables

I have a data set where n participants were asked to give a yes or no response to of 12 different (and distinct) stimuli. Each stimulus fits into 1 of 3 categories and an item for each category appears 4 times.

This all fits neatly into a 3x2 contingency table, but each participant is contributing to the table 12 times! I would compare categories with a chi-square test, but the assumption of independence is broken.

Are there alternatives that would account for this? Should I be looking at totaling the responses into 0 to 4 scores?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to model this using multivariate logistic regression.  This can probably be fit in R with `lme4::glmer`, some information is at [Fitting multivariate linear mixed model in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10429/fitting-multivariate-linear-mixed-model-in-r), follow the links and references therein!

This would need a random intercept for each respondent, shared among the 12 logistic regression, so would really be a multivariate model.